# Riemann Sum Approximation (confused...)

Tags: calculus, approximation, riemann-sum

I'm having trouble determining when a left-hand approximation is an over/under estimate for a given function.

[image]

For example, for the graph above $f(x)$=$ln(x)$ and the function is increasing for all $x$ > 0.Since the function continues to increase, doe that mean the left-hand approximation would be an underestimate? $$\\$$
Update:

[image]

Comment: Yes.  Try drawing the rectangles for a Riemann sum approximation.  Since they are 'anchored' at the left side, the curve lies above the rectangles, and therefore its area exceeds the areas of the rectangles.

Comment: @NickPeterson so would that mean the right-hand approximation would be an overestimate?

Comment: Yep.  Again: draw the rectangles.

Comment: @NickPeterson is the updated image in my question correct for the left-hand?

Comment: Yep! That's the image I was suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the function is always increasing, that means the left-hand sum will be an underestimate and the right-hand sum will be an overestimate.

When the function is always decreasing, that means the right-hand sum will be an underestimate and the left-hand sum will be an overestimate. $$\\$$

For the function $f$($x$)=$ln$($x$), it is always increasing.

This site may help you understand better: http://www.shmoop.com/definite-integrals/compare-left-right-sum.html